# How to test Application in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, android-emulator

This is the first time,I am working on `mobile` devices.If I modified any code in my local system,before push the code,I want to test how it is working(functionality,view) in `mobile` with the corresponding  (`http://localhost:3001/mobile.html`) link.

For this, I seen some `mobile emulators`,but no one not allowing me to test local Application.

If anybody knows,suggest me with the links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of `localhost`, you have to use `10.0.2.2` if you are using emulators. How ever for real devices, you have to use actual ip(like `192.168.1.2` etc.) instead of `localhost`.Provided, they are in the same network.

So, your link should be similar to this: `http://192.168.1.2:3001/mobile.html`

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion.It showing `Requested page can't be displayed. Please check the url`.

Comment: Check your ip address properly. I gave 192.168.1.2 just as example.